# HDMI-VGA adapter stops working

Tags: hdmi, vga, display-adapter

I am trying to use an older monitor (VGA only) with a new computer. The computer only has DVI-D and HDMI ports, so I bought a HDMI-VGA adapter.

However while it worked for the first hour or so, after that the monitor would just go blank and say 'no signal'. If I pull apart the VGA cable and the adapter and put them back together, it works again, but at this point it just lasts a minute or so, then the signal is gone again.

I have even taken the adapter back and gotten another one, but it has the same behavior.

I guess the obvious thing is the VGA cable, which I can replace of course. Just wondering what might be going on and is this likely the cable problem?

Any advice would be welcome!

Comment: well I haven't done anything yet, played with the settings but still the same behavior. I will change the VGA line tomorrow, and I also wonder if grounding could be an issue

Comment: well I have hooked it up to my old laptop which has VGA slot and the monitor is working fine. I am stumped, about to give up on this old monitor.